# what is the global variable `content` in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser, global-variables

I just noticed that Firefox had defined a global variable called `content` which is equal to `window`.

```
'content' in window && window.content === window // true on Firefox
                                                 // false on other browsers
```

What is it? How is it typically used? Is it a browser specified feature or something in specification (Does it belong to some specification)? Should I use it or avoid using it?

P.S. I had tested on Chrome, IE 11, Edge, Opera 12. They both report that there is no variable called `content` on `window`. Firefox 52 ESR report true for above expression.

Comment: [`Window.content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/content).

Comment: @Xufox My understanding to the MDN page, it is talking about a feature for XUL. Should this also be applied to HTML?

Comment: @tsh It says it's useful in XUL windows, it doesn't say it only exists in them.

Comment: @Xufox Thanks for your link. It solved my question. Could you post in as an answer so that it could be accepted?

Comment: @tsh I can’t only post the link as an answer. I don’t know much about `window.content` and I don’t want to just copy-paste the MDN page. Basically, I’m not sure how to write a _good_ answer to this, so I’ll leave it to someone else.

Comment: @Xufox you could vote to close as asking for a resource :-)

Comment: @Bergi some edits had been made to make it more clearly and on-topic.